# Specific path to Youtube_dl files in Centos

Tags: linux, path, centos, youtube-dl

The recent path to youtube_dl is "/usr/local/bin/youtube_dl". I want to edit some files in youtube_dl, but couldn't find the files to it.

Does it has any specific path or i have to unzip it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change youtube-dl, the easiest way is to follow the develop instructions and use git to check out the repository, with the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl.git
cd youtube-dl
python -m youtube_dl
```

For more information, refer to the [youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/#developer-instructions). Alternatively, you can also download the [source release](https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl.tar.gz).

---

Now, if you *really* want to work from your /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl file, here's the secret: youtube-dl makes use of cPython's ability to [execute a zip file](http://bugs.python.org/issue1739468). The [file you downloaded](https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl) is just a zip file with a short extra header. A good zip program should be able to extract it for you:

```
$ unzip youtube-dl
Archive:  youtube-dl
warning [youtube-dl]:  22 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
  inflating: youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py
  ...
  inflating: __main__.py
```

If your zip program doesn't support skipping bytes, you can use a hex editor to remove the 22 bytes before `50 4B 03 04`, and then unzip it.

Comment: yeah i want to add "--bind-ip" to work from youtube-dl

Comment: Hello @phihag, can you please tell me how can i repack to youtube-dl after unzipping

Comment: You can repack by simply invoking `make`.

Comment: @phohag couldn't create youtube_dl using "make" command. It says "makefile" not found.

Comment: @Jaki This will only work with options 1 and 2 (that's why I mentioned those first in the answer). The binary does not come with build instructions and other developer tools, so you'll have to cobble together the commands yourself.

Comment: @phohag yeah now i get it. Thanks for the help.